# bq jobs summary using command line tool

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there any way to get the list of load job(not query job) summary using big query command only?. I know there is a command to get the summary of bq jobs, but it returns the  query and load jobs sumary. Also is there any document where i can see the list of bq commands?

$ bq  ls -j --max_results=5
                  jobId                    Job Type    State      Start Time      Duration

---

dsdsdsdssssssssssssssssdsdsdsdss6c67     query      RUNNING   31 Dec 19:06:00
  dsdsdsdssssssssssssssssdsdsdsdss6c66     query      SUCCESS   31 Dec 19:04:54   0:00:06
  r314343434343434343434343434343          load       SUCCESS   31 Dec 19:04:25   0:01:33
  dsdsdsdssssssssssssssssdsdsdsdss52e7     query      SUCCESS   31 Dec 19:03:34   0:00:05
  314343434343434343434343434345            load       SUCCESS   31 Dec 19:02:53   0:00:18

Answer (score 2):

Can you use "load" filtering like below (in which it tries to match result lines with the 2nd column "load" and discard non-matched lines):

```
bq ls -j | awk 'NR <= 2 || $2=="load" {print $0}' | head -n7
```

Results look like:

[image]

To check commands, you can do

```
bq help
bq help <command>
```

or refer to [bq cli_tools](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool).